# Drag - drop custom SKSpriteNode position issue

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm my game I'm using a custom SKSpriteNode which the player are going to be able to drag and drop at a position of his/hers desire.

My custom node is made of this code in file DraggableNode.swift:

```
    class DraggableNode : SKSpriteNode {

    var nodeSelected : SKNode?

    init() {
        let texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "draggableNode_1")
        super.init(texture: texture, color: UIColor.white, size: texture.size())
        self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        self.zPosition = 1
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        if let touch = touches.first {
            let location = touch.location(in: self)

            let touchedNodes = self.nodes(at: location)
            for node in touchedNodes.reversed() {
                nodeSelected = node
            }
        }
    }

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        if let touch = touches.first, let node = self.nodeSelected {
            let touchLocation = touch.location(in: self)
            node.position = touchLocation
        }
    }

    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        nodeSelected = nil
    }

    override func touchesCancelled(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        nodeSelected = nil
    }
}
```

In my GameScene.swift I add the custom node in this way:

```
let node = DraggableNode()
node.position = CGPoint(x: randomX, y: randomY)
self.addChild(node)
```

Now, the problem is that when I start to drag the node it's all jump and is placed a total random place - sometimes even out of the screenarea.

I wonder if the problem consists of the fact that it's a custom node inherited from a SKSpriteNode?

If anyone can point me in the right direction, I'd be a happy man :-)

Comment: I'm wondering if it's because you are moving the object within the "touches" methods and it's confusing the user-interaction aspect.  How about storing the desired position in the "touches" methods and only moving to that place within the scene `update` method?

Comment: I think it's because you're using `let location = touch.location(in: self)` within the node itself, not the scene it is added too, so it only 'sees' its local coordinate space. Instead I think you might want to move the node in the actual scene code

Comment: henrik-dmg is the closest one. You are moving your touch in the nodes system, not the nodes parent system, which is what position uses. Also, when you move the touch off of the node, you are no longer capable of moving it since you are not directly touching it. This is something your scene class or a larger node managing touches needs to handle.

Comment: Ahh, I see, yes. However, I'm having trouble in my GameScene with the touch due to the nodes "original" touch method. I've assigned a name to the draggableNode in its own class. In GameScene.swift's touchBegan method I did "if node.name == "draggableNode" { print("Node touched")" nothing happens.

Comment: I discovered something here. When I set 'isUserInteractionEnabled' to 'true' in the draggableNode's class it calls the 'touchesBegan' method in that class. If i set 'isUserInteractionEnabled' to 'false' it class the 'touchesBegan' method in GameScene. Is there a way to "combine" these two?